# more Swiss media confirmed -- is "media" a mass noun?

Tags: comprehension

Example with [a context](http://nypost.com/2015/03/15/swiss-media-reveals-more-about-putins-girlfriend-baby/):

> **More Swiss media** confirmed Saturday that Vladimir Putin is the father of a bouncing baby girl, giving the lie to the Kremlin’s determined efforts to deny the story.

Is the word *media* used as a mass noun in this paragraph? If so, then what does this actually mean? Swiss media companies collectively? My understanding is that it says there are now even more news agencies in Switzerland that report on the story about Putin's girlfriend giving birth to a baby girl. Am I right?

Comment: Average native speakers of American English treat "media" as a singular noun "the media" and they mean "TV news in general" when they use it. More highly educated speakers, on the other hand, treat it as a plural noun and for them it also includes internet blogs, radio, newspapers, tabloids and e-tabloids, and so forth. Pick your poison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

"Media" is a plural noun referring to news outlets of all kinds - newspapers, TV, radio, internet, town criers, etc. If it reports news, it is a news medium, and thus part of the (news) media.